# How to remove text content of span when ajax response is same for 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have written ajax which gets called every second using `setInterval()` function.

I want to use the ajax response to set text content of a span using innerText.

ajax is getting called every second and is receiving response data from URL.

When data from response remains unchanged for 5 seconds, I want the text content of span tag to be removed.

How can I put condition in ajax call to check if data from response is unchanged for 5 seconds?

```
setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",

          url: "/data",  // URL to your view that serves new info

      })
      .done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      });
}, 1000)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you declare a variable with the prev response and an accum? Then you just need to ask every time the data arrives if the prev response is the same as the current and if the accum is equal to 5 or higher than 5. If true remove the span if not increase the accum or/and update the prev response var...

Comment: You could have a variable outside the setInterval() function to which records the number of times the data is repeated and and  u need to store the previous response data and inside .done block u compare previous response and the current response and increament the counter and if counter equal to 5 remove text content else assign the value of the counter to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the time and the data whenever the data changes.

```js
let dataRecord = {
  time: 0,
  data: null
};

...

let dataChanged = (d1, d2) => {
    /* compare d1 & d2, return true if different */
}

.done(function(data) {
  let nowTime = new Date().getTime();

  if (dataChanged(data, dataRecord.data)) {
    dataRecord = {
      time: nowTime,
      data
    };

    // update your span content here

  } else if (nowTime - dataRecord.time > 5000) {

    // remove your span content here

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var prevValue = null;

setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",

          url: "/data",  // URL to your view that serves new info

      })
      .done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         if (prevValue === null) {
             prevValue = data;       //set initial value on first call
         } else {
            if (data == prevValue) {      //check if data is the same
                i++;                      //add 1 to counter
                if(i == 5) {              //if counter reaches 5
                    $('span').text('');   //hide span text
                }
            } else {                      //if data is not same   
                i = 0;                    //reset counter
            }
         }
      });
}, 1000)
```

Comment: `setInterval((), 1000)` will not occur ever second. It's better to record the actual time and compare that.